# How to build an SQL query that directs two different columns to the same reference column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am getting a bit confused with this basic SQL question, I was hoping you could give me a hint about what am I doing wrong:

I have a main table with different players:

```
id  | name
----+-----
1   | John
2   | Paul
3   | Robert
```

And another table that stores their matches

```
date      |  player_home  |  player_away
----------+---------------+-------------
2012-03-21|  1            |  2
2012-04-10|  2            |  3
```

I am trying to build a query that outputs the names of both players for a given date, but the name of the same player is being repeated in both fields:

This retrieves nothing:

```
SELECT date, player_home, name, player_away, name 
FROM games, players 
WHERE date = (DATE '2012-03-21') 
AND games.player_home = players.id 
AND games.player_away = players.id;
```

And if I remove the second AND, it retrieves the same name (John) for both players:

```
date      |  player_home  |  name   |   player_away  |   name
----------+---------------+---------+----------------+-------
2012-03-21|  1            |  John   |   2            |   John
```

When the name in the second "name" field should be "Paul".

What is the right way to build this query?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the `players` table twice and use different alias names for the tables

```
SELECT g.date, p1.name as home_name, p2.name as away_name
FROM games g
JOIN players p1 ON g.player_home = p1.id 
JOIN players p2 ON g.player_away = p2.id 
WHERE g.date = (DATE '2012-03-21')
```

Comment: Excellent, I was guessing it had to be something with join... I also didn't know about the alias thing. Useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT date, player_home, players_home.name, player_away, player_away.name 
FROM games
left outer join players players_home on player_home=players.id
left outer join players players_away on player_away=players.id
WHERE date = (DATE '2012-03-21') ;
```